How to remove apostrophe before data cells in Excel?
I want to remove the apostrophes before data ubicated in cells in Excel. The apostrophe is hidden but when you press F2 to edit the cell, it appears. It cannot be removed. Not when I open a new sheet or a new Excel document. I need to remove this character because I work with data in an ERP and the apostrophe is generating an error.

I believe you can range.replace Chr(39), ""; please post the script you've tried thusfar, by editing your post.

You cannot delete a formatting character in this way.

If there is no other formatting in cells you can apply Range(...).ClearFormats or Cells.ClearFormats in the entire sheet.

Does it help to remove the apostrophe?

Yes, but it will also remove other types of formatting if they were used. It's easy to check.

Your answer is not complete since ClearFormats itself doesn't remove the apostrophe. What else should be done?

I guess cell formatting isn't used when data import into the ERP system, so this way is acceptable.

The apostrophe as the first character in an Excel cell forces the content to be interpreted as text instead of a formula. Some characters in Excel, including dash -, at @, equals = will always trigger specific Excel behaviour.
If you bulk remove the ' character, your Excel file might be speckled with errors afterwards.
You may want to review the cell content and determine if maybe you could start with a leading space character instead of a ' character, which might be easier for the ERP system to deal with.
